# Preview Theme functionality in Cakephp3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In my **AppController** i'm assigning the **active theme** like this:

```
$this->viewBuilder()->theme($this->Themes->active_theme());
```

I've created a page which shows all my themes (I'm using a **json file** for this), i want to add a preview theme functionality to every theme in my page just like *wordpress, drupal* etc.

I'm not sure how to can i **temporarily load a theme** using app controller for **previewing purpose**.

Any help on how this functionality works and how can i do it in Cakephp would save my day.

Comment: Do you want the other theme to be applied when a GET-parameter is present? Or when should the preview theme be applied?

Comment: @MBosman Whenever user clicks the preview button the current loaded theme must not be changed rather a temporary preview must be loaded just like we do in wordpress.

Answer (score -1):

In your preview function, call `$this->viewBuilder()->theme($previewTheme);`? Seems pretty straight-forward, am I missing something?

Comment: I have a link (Click here to Preview), How am i supposed to change the theme at runtime?

Comment: In your question, you say you're calling
`$this->viewBuilder()->theme($this->Themes->active_theme());`
This is already "changing the theme at runtime". All you need to do in your preview function is call `theme` again, with the name of the theme you want to preview.